# how to make an effect of a clicked button for 0.5 seconds?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make

```css
background-color: green;
border: 5px solid green;
```

for a button only for 0.5 seconds effect after a click, to animate a click. How can I do it?

Comment: Look into [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and possibly CSS animations

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some JavaScript to detect the click and change change the styles. You could possibly make do with a CSS animation, but you'd still need JavaScript to trigger it, so I'm not sure it's worth the effort to make it work in CSS anyways:

```js
function setStyles(el, styles) {
  Object.entries(styles).map(
    ([property, value]) => el.style[property] = value
  )
}

const btn = document.querySelector("button")
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // capture original styles
  const origStyles = {
    background: btn.style.background,
    border: btn.style.border,
  }
  
  // set temp styles
  setStyles(btn, {
    background: "green", 
    border: "5px solid green",
  })

  // reset original styles after 0.5 seconds
  window.setTimeout(() => setStyles(btn, origStyles), 500)
})
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but can u tell me how to make a smooth glow effect for a button click?

Comment: @vifok32694 There are plenty of resources for that on the internet that would do a better job than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.foo-button {
  /* Disable OS styling */
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  /* Rounded corners */
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Text padding */
  padding: 6px 12px;
  /* Normal color */
  background: #2442a0;
  /* Text style */
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  /* Animation (“transition” timing) */
  transition: .5s background;
}

.foo-button:active {
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background: green;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: #2442a0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="foo-button">Button Text</button>
```